# Which position value changes when you use an SKAction on an SKSpriteNode? And how would I account for the position changes?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, position, skaction

I'm trying to use an SKAction to move my sprites. However, I noticed that after moving the sprites, their position values still remained the same. With some research, I learned that (correct me if I'm wrong) the sprites' position values are actually their location relative to the parent view, and that it was the parent view's position value that had actually changed, and not the sprites'. Only when I checked, the parent view's position value also hadn't changed.

So which position value actually changes?? And how would I go about accounting for the change in position when accessing the sprites' position values? (Since a lot of my game's logic is dependent on their position values)

Here's my code:

```swift
let fall = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -85, duration: 0.2)

print("Original position \(gift.position)")
gift.run(fall)
print("New position \(gift.position)") // Both print the same value
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to show more details, like the actual code where you create the actions and run them.  Movement actions will change the position of the node that is running them, and that position is relative to the node's parent (which may be the view if those nodes are at the top level).  Some possible issues if it's not working might be creating an action but not having the node run it, or having the scene or the node paused.

Comment: @bg2b Sorry, just added my code. Also, I think my node runs the action correctly, because it does actually move on the scene. Though the position values don't seem to change, so I'm just really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `gift.run(fall)` is *scheduling* an action that will happen over the course of 0.2 seconds, not waiting for it to finish.  At 60 frames/second, that means the sprite will reach its final position only after 12 frames.  If you print the gift's position at each step in `update(_:)`, you'll see that it is indeed changing.

Since the `run` does not wait for the action to complete, the sprite hasn't had a chance to move at all when the second `print` is executed.

If you want something to happen only after an action completes, you have various possibilities.  A common way is to add a completion block; see Apple's documentation on getting started with actions: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/getting_started_with_actions.  Or if you want the same node to do multiple things in order, you can make a composite `SKAction`, like with the `sequence` or `repeat` initializers.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!!